# Why Angularjs validate don't work with input[type="number"]

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am trying to validate with Angularjs. Only when [type=text], ng-pattern works well. When [type="number"] ng-pattern is not working, but required, min, max still work.

```
<input type="number" name="number" ng-model="myNumber" ng-pattern="reg" required />
```

[https://jsfiddle.net/o4hr219m/](https://jsfiddle.net/dengjun/o4hr219m/)

I tried add attr[novalidate] for form make browser don't validate, but didn't work.

Everyone have other ideas?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `type="number"` you can use `$error.number` instead `$error.pattern` 
as angular is not going to bind value to model until value is not valid

```
<span ng-show="myForm.number.$error.number">no valid</span>
```

please see demo below

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.reg = /^[0-9]*$/;


});
```

```css
.error {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
    <form name="myForm">
      <label>Value Number</label>
      <input type="number" name="number" ng-pattern="reg" ng-model="value.number" /><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.number.$error.number">no valid</span>
      <br/>Curent error for Value Number
      <pre>{{myForm.number.$error | json}}</pre> 

      <hr/>

      <label>Value Number</label>
      <input type="text" name="text" ng-pattern="reg" ng-model="value.text" /><span class="error" ng-show="myForm.text.$error.pattern">no valid</span>
      <br/>Curent error for Value Number
      <pre>{{myForm.text.$error | json}}</pre> 
      <hr/>



      <input type="submit" value="submit" ng-disable="myForm.$invalid" />
    </form>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: pattern always invalid, remove quotes

Comment: @yunandtidus well spoted

Comment: Thank you for @sylwester, I am using with Angularjs1.2.1. Angularjs1.3.0 works well

Answer (score 1):

Updated fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/o4hr219m/5/

JS

```
angular.module('pmsApp', []).controller('testCtrl',function($scope){
    $scope.reg= /^[0-9]\\d*$/;
})
```

HTML

```
<input ng-model="number" type="number" name="number" ng-pattern="reg"/>
```

With your fiddle:

- Module was not defined and ng-app was not used
- Angular was loaded on load (put in head or body instead)
- **No ng-model on input so validation won't work**
- Don't wrap your regular expression with quotes